# How to test Linux on hidpi support without real hardware?

Tags: linux, gnome, xfce

I'm considering buying a laptop with a hidpi screen, but am unsure how good things will look.  I'd like to run XFCE or gnome flashback on it, but would like a way to test things before spending $2k.  Is there a way (perhaps with a VM or something) I can test on non hidpi hardware to know if things will scale properly on the real thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the virtual screen size in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
        SubSection "Display"
                Virtual 3600 1200
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I have yet to find a truly aesthetically pleasing setup with my HiDPI (3200 x 1800) display with anything except plasma, which pretty much worked out of the box. with Gnome I found there were a [lot of things to balance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) and these are [still being worked on](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/improved-ubuntu-hidpi-support-in-gnome).